# Render alternative content if user is logged in instead of redirecting to user/uid

Tags: forms, users, routes, theming

I have a menu router with type MENU_CALLBACK and it's 'page callback' property points to a function that implements render API, as follow:

```
 /** Implements hook_menu **/
function custom_render_menu() {
  $items['register-profile'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_render_register_profile',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/** Implements callback page for register-profile **/
function custom_render_register_profile() {
  $user_register_form = drupal_get_form('user_registration_form');
  $markup = user_is_logged_in() ? t("Alternative Content") : drupal_render($user_register_form);
  $output = array( '#markup' => $markup);
  return $output;
}
```

If the user is not logged in, the registration form displays correctly, but if the user is logged in, the page was redirected to user/uid router, showing user's profile. How can I display an alternative content instead of redirecting the user to their user page?

Comment: Where does the redirect happen?

Comment: when a logged in user accesses localhost/register-profile.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you provided that will cause a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's answer helped me on this. For some reason, if you had called drupal_get_form('user_register_form'), even if you assigned it to a variable that isn't being concatenated to '#markup', drupal will still go through the process of checking if the user is logged in or not.

Calling the drupal_get_form('user_register_form') right when assigning the '#markup' does the trick.

```
function custom_render_register_profile() {
  $output = array( 
    '#markup' => user_is_logged_in() ? t("Alternative Content") : drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_registration_form')); 
  );
  return $output;
}
```

**edited:**
The code above will work but will result in a strict warning: only variables should be passed by reference.
Use elaborated if statement instead:

```
function custom_render_register_profile() {
  $output = array();
  if(user_is_logged_in()) {
    $output['#markup'] = t('Alt. Content');
  }else{
    $form_registration = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
    $output['#markup'] = drupal_render($form_registration);
  }

 $output += array(
  //Add more attributes to your $output
 );
 return $output;
}
```

As to why the ternary version of the if statement wouldn't work, I'm not sure.

Comment: I still don't see the redirect. Can you provide some code for user_registration_form?

Comment: I must have misspelled that. It is 'user_register_form' On the default user login screen, it is the form rendered under first tab, labelled: "Create New Account". I bet the same behaviour would show I was programmatically rendering 'user_login', in the same manner.

Comment: Despite its name, `drupal_get_form()` doesn't just build the form, it processes the input including executing the redirect. Btw there's no need to render the form directly, you can just return it - and allow it be modified by `hook_page_alter()` before final rendering.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
/** Implements callback page for register-profile **/
function custom_render_register_profile() {
  $markup = user_is_logged_in() ? t("Alternative Content") : drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_registration_form'));
  $output = array( '#markup' => $markup);
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. I'm so puzzled now. In fact for a kick, I tried this:
    `$bazinga = TRUE
    $markup = $bazinga ? t("Alt Content") : drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));`
And it will still redirect to user/nid

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_render_register_profile() {
global $user;
global $base_url;
$uid=$user->uid;
if($uid)
{
drupal_goto('url where you want to take login user..like $base_url./node/1');
}
else
{
  $user_register_form = drupal_get_form('user_registration_form');
  $markup =drupal_render($user_register_form);
  $output = array( '#markup' => $markup);
  return $output;
}
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't I use just one menu router to do this? Shouldn't the render API knows what I put into the '#markup'?